# Storing an array in C

Tags: c

Context: I need to write a program that will accept inputs which will be stored into the array. Before storing in to the array, the inputted number must be checked if it already exists in the array or not. If it does not exist, it is stored into the array. If it exists, another input will be asked.

Now, my code will get inputs from the user, but the code will only work for the first input. It won't work for the second until the last input. Any pointers?

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 5

main()
{
int i;
arr[size];
input;

printf("This program will accept ");
printf("unique inputted numbers that will be stored");
printf(" in an array\n");
for(i = 0;i < size;i++)
{
    printf("Enter input: ");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        
    if (unique(arr,input,i))
        arr[i] = input;
    else
        i--;                                                             
   //decrement i because ask for input again
}
for(i = 0;i < size;i++)
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);

}

int unique(int arr[],int input,int i)
{
int n, z;
n = 0;
z = 1;

while(i > n)
{
    if(arr[n] == input)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        z = 0; 
        break;
    }
    else
        n=1;
        break;
}
    
return z;
}
```

Comment: Doing the `scanf` in the `unique` function is extremely bad design. The only thing `unique` should do is return 0 `input` is already in the array.

Comment: Also declaration as `arr[size];` and  `input;` have been outdated for quite some time now (not sure, maybe 20 years or so). Use `int arr[size];` and `int  input;`.

Comment: So... `unique` for `i==1` will return 1, so far so good. For higher `i` it will compare input with `arr[0]` and tell you whether they are unequal. If they are equal, it will read and discard a number. Are you sure you got that function entirely right?

Comment: You should turn up compiler warnings and read them. For GCC or clang use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. You should provide proper types for `main` and for your variables. You should provide a prototype for `unique` before you call that function.

Comment: Fill another array with the numbers and keep it sorted (qsort). When there's a new entry, search (bsearch) the array to see if it already exists. If so, print an error message accordingly. Else, fill another entry in the array. And go to step 2.

Comment: @Haris I suspect that the approach using qsort is overkill and too complicated for the OP's level. His original approach is OK at a beginner's level (naively searching if the number is already in the array), but the program logic simply wrong.

Comment: Consider replacing `scanf()` with `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)` coupled with `strtol(,,)` or `strtod(,,)` functions to convert.

Comment: @Jabberwocky you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong at multiple levels:

- The logic in the unique function is wrong.
- Doing the `scanf` in the `unique` function is extremely bad design. The only thing `unique` should do is return 0 if `input` is already in the array.
- You have used implicit variable declarations here: `arr[size]; input;`, it should be `int arr[size]; int input;`.
- You should use descriptive variable names which makes your code easier to understand.

This is a working example (explanations in comments).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5   // use capitals for macros (this is a convention)

int unique(int arr[], int value, int arrsize)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i] == value)
    {
      return 0;   // value found in array
    }
  }

  return 1;       // value not found in array
}


void Test(int arr[], int arrsize, int value, int expected)
{
  if (unique(arr, arrsize, value) != expected)
    printf("Test failed for value %d\n", value);
}

void runtests()
{
  int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
  Test(arr, 4, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr), 1);
  Test(arr, 1, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr), 0);
  Test(arr, 3, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr), 0);
}


#define size 5

int main()
{
  int i;
  int arr[size];   // declare int variable
  int input;       // declare int variable

  printf("This program will accept unique inputted numbers that will be stored in an array\n");

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("Enter input %d: ", i + 1); 
    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (unique(arr, input, i))  // value already in the array?
      arr[i] = input;           //  no => put it there
    else
    {                           // yes => ask again
      printf("  >> %d is already in the array\n");
      i--;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
```

There are two more functions `Test` and `runtests` in this code. They are not called by this code, but they can be very useful for debugging. As an exercise try to understand why they can be useful during the debug phase of your code.

Comment: This works great! Thank you for the explanations and I'm sorry for the crazy designs. I'm still learning C and am currently an IT freshman. Thank you for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but overcomplicating it slightly.

Let's take a step back and think about this at a high level.  You want to store unique inputs in the array, up to the size of the array.  In pseudocode:

```
while array not full
  prompt for and read next input
  if input not already in array
    store input
  else
    write a message 
  end if
end while
```

What's really key is that you only need one input statement - your `unique` function should *only* check for the presence of the input value in the array and return true or false.  It shouldn't do any input of its own.

So your main loop is more like

```
while ( i < size )
{
  fputs( "Gimme a number: ", stdout );
  /**
   * Break out of the loop if there's an error 
   * on input.
   */
  if ( scanf( "%d", &input ) != 1 )
    break;

  if ( unique( arr, i, input ) )
    arr[i++] = input;
  else
    printf( "%d already exists in the array, try again.\n", input );
}
```

All your `unique` function needs to do is cycle through the elements of the array.  By calling `unique` with `i` instead of `size` it will only check array elements that have been written to *so far* and not bother with unassigned elements.  This way you don't have to make sure that all of the array elements have been initialized to some known, out-of-band value that's guaranteed to compare unequal to any valid input.

You'll need to compile against C99 or later and include `stdbool.h` to use the `bool` type and the `true` and `false` constants.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
...
bool unique( int *arr, size_t size, int input )
{
  bool result = true;

  for( size_t i = 0; i < size && result; i++ )
    if ( arr[i] == input )
      result = false;

  return result;
}
```

If you want to get really terse, you could directly assign the result of the Boolean expression to `result`:

```
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < size && result; i++ )
     result = (arr[i] == input);
```

but people will hit you.  It's perfectly valid code, but a little eye-stabby, and most programmers aren't used to seeing Boolean expressions outside of an `if`, `for`, `while`, or `switch` statement control expression.

Finally, some suggestions:

- Fix your formatting.  The compiler doesn't care, but it makes it easier for other people to understand what you're trying to do and to spot mistakes.
- The presence of `main()` in your code suggests you're using C89 or K&R C.  C99 did away with implicit `int` declarations.  You *really* should define `main` as either `int main( void )` or `int main( int argc, char **argv )`.  Furthermore, you should move to a compiler that supports later versions of C (C11 or C18).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers! I'm gonna update my compiler and gonna give this a try. Thank you so much!